# Learning to optimize with Assembly

Tags: c++, optimization, books

I am a second year student of Computer Games Technology. I recently finished my first prototype of my "kind" of own pathfinder (that doesn't use A* instead a geometrical approach/pattern recognition, the pathfinder just needs the knowledge about the terrain that is in his view to make decisions, because I wanted an AI that could actually explore, if the terrain is already known, then it will walk the shortest way easily, because the pathfinder has a memory of nodes).

Anyway my question is more general:
How do I start optimizing algorithms/loops/for_each/etc. using Assembly, although general tips are welcome.
I am specifically looking for good books, because it is really hard to find good books on this topic. There are some small articles out there like [this one](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/news/38515/A_Low_Level_Curriculum_for_C_and_C_.php), but still isn't enough knowledge to optimize an algorithm/game...

I hope there is a modern good book out there, that I just couldn't find...

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but explorative (so called adaptive) A* has been investigated and has really good performance (meaning you won't need to optimize it using ASM). Have a look at [D* Lite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D*).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'll be the one going against the grain here and say, it is never too early to *learn* about optimizations, especially assembly optimizations and more importantly, debugging in assembly. I believe that you will gain the maximum benefit of it if you are a student (because then you have very little to lose [i.e. time/money wise]) and everything to gain.

If you are in the industry and not tasked with tinkering around in assembly, then don't. Otherwise, if you are a student or have time in general, I would find the time to learn to disassemble programs and see if I can come up with a better solution than the compiler. If I can't, who cares! I just learned how to write as well as compiler and that is a HUGE plus when you are faced with a bug in release code (with no debug symbols) and staring at the disassembly because that's the only thing you can look at.

**The answer**

This is one of the best resource I have found for learning about optimizations.

http://www.agner.org/optimize/

**The rant**

If you read some articles by major developers (for example, reasoning behind the making of EASTL and closer inspection of the code will lead you to comments like **did this because GCC is terrible at inlining this if statement** which will tell you, what the majority of people tell you **trust the compiler** is not always right, ESPECIALLY in game development) and then set foot in the industry you will find that optimizations are an everyday thing and knowing what the assembly output means is a big plus. Also, people don't seem to realize (especially on stackoverflow) that profiling games is very hard and not always accurate.

There is a caveat though. You can spend time optimizing something and later on realize that was time wasted. But what did you learn? You learned not to repeat that same mistake in a similar circumstance.

What SO is now taking is in my opinion a religious stance to the statement **don't optimize until you profile** and **don't worry, the compiler knows better than you**. It hinders learning. I know experts in the industry who are paid very good money (and I mean VERY good money) to fiddle around in assembly to optimize the game and debug it because the compiler is bad at it or simply cannot help you, because, well, it cannot (GPU related crashes, crashes where data involved is impossible to read in a debugger etc. etc.)!

What if someone who loves doing that, hasn't fully realized it yet, asks the question here and is turned away/off by the many answers **compiler knows better than you!** and never becomes one of those highly paid programmers?

One final thought. If you start doing this early, you will find that soon you will start writing code that is at worst, has no performance improvements whatsoever because the compiler optimized it the same way or at best, has some performance improvements because now the compiler can optimize it. In either case, it has become habit, and you are no slower at writing code this way than what you did before. A couple of examples are (there are many more):

1. Pre-incrementing unless you really want post-increment
2. Writing loops for containers using a constant local size variable rather than calling size() on the container within the loop.

**EDIT:** Update after 8 more years in the industry. Learn assembly. Learn how optimizers work and the assembly they generate (CompilerExplorer is a great tool for that). I have run across countless crashes in Test builds (optimized builds for internal testing) where you cannot rely on the debugger even with debug symbols. The compiler has optimized out too many things and the assembly is your only source of valuable information to find the bug from the crash dump. Each build takes 30-40min if you're lucky and first in the build queue - so you cannot rely on some traditional techniques to isolate the bug. Multiplayer makes things worse. Knowing assembly and how to read optimized assembly will simply make you better and ultimately more valuable to the team.

Comment: Good point about optimizing compilers. They are great to have, but they are far from perfect, and unlike what some people believe it is usually not hard to find a simple optimization that a compiler did not make.

Comment: It should be noted that there is a difference between "learning to read assembly" and "learning to _optimize_ with assembly". The two are not the same thing, and your answer doesn't really touch on using assembly to _implement_ optimizations. Reading assembly is a useful skill, as it can help in debugging and spotting places where the compiler isn't doing something right. But that's very different from actually using assembly to _write_ optimized routines, which requires deep knowledge of instruction scheduling for a specific CPU. And it's also something you didn't cover.

Comment: Also, "I just learned how to write as well as compiler" No, you did not. You looked how one specific routine was compiled for one specific CPU. Learning how to implement optimized assembly routines requires more than looking at how the compiler compiled one routine. You have to understand _why_ the compiler chose those opcodes in that order to reproduce that specific C++ code. And that requires intimate knowledge of the CPU, instruction scheduling, and so forth. Generalizing this requires _years_ of experience; you won't get it by just decoding a couple of routines.

Comment: So, -1 for A: not actually answering the question about how to write assembly-optimized routines. B: misrepresenting how easy it is to learn how to beat the compiler at writing assembly-optimized routines. And C: encouraging a programmer to look at assembly-level optimizations _before_ algorithm-level optimizations. Even those highly paid "experts in the industry" would tell you that that's putting the cart before the horse.

Comment: This looks to me like a bad case of the OP accepting the answer he wanted to hear, not the answer that the majority of industry professionals suggest to be the right one. Can't say we didn't warn you.

Comment: @NicolBolas: The problem with your overall reasoning is that you contradict yourself. You say yourself "Generalizing this requires years of experience", but where does it start? We learn Calculus, in what, high school? And start going over very tough differential problems in first year of undergraduate. Why? Why don't we generalize the problems and when we have `enough experience` do we attempt to solve them? It is because learning is a very involved and lengthy process. It is very difficult, and if you are in the industry, you will know this already, to learn new skills drastically...

Comment: different than your current simply because you will not be `asked` to work on the `new` skills you will want to learn. You will simply be working with what you have done for the past few years. Very few people have the time/energy later on in life to expend on drastically different subject matter. I consider this to be one of the cases. You noticed that I did not address the `writing in assembly` part. This is because that is OPs own choice. I wanted to go against the grain of the popular answers here because of what I believe is true. I simply pointed OP in a direction...

Comment: whether it is good or bad (obviously I will be biased and say it is the right direction) is up to him/her to decide which is I hope after giving it much thought and deliberation. I don't care for points, so you can `-1` all you want if that makes you feel better. I simply gave a different perspective, the opposite of which has a religious/cult like following in here and in SO. If someone asks "how do I optimize this" or "learn to optimize this", I am of the opinion that instead of saying "Let the compiler do it for you" or "You are not smart enough!", simply point them in the right direction..

Comment: and let them decide for themselves. If you don't know the answer (perhaps because you also have been following blindly the teachings that the all mighty compiler knows best, and that you should focus on your algorithms and that's that) then don't answer. "Don't play with fire, trust me" is not the right answer. Instead, programmers should learn to control it. If they can't, and they get burnt, then they should by all means stop and go along their business. But if they can control it, they just opened so many more doors. This can only happen in the early stages...

Comment: (yes of course there are exceptions) when the programmer is young, has lots of time, risks of trying new things are very low etc. This is THE time to encourage them to look at new things, to dissect things we rely on. They will make mistakes and learn from them and hopefully, later on, will not repeat them; unlike others who never touched upon the matter because of the fear of it or simply because `experts told me so` and may make the mistakes when the stakes are extremely high.

Comment: @NickWiggil: Could you point me to the `majority` of industry professionals who say not to touch assembly programming, understanding disassembly and how to optimize code simply because I have an interest in it? Why would they say that? It makes no sense. I want to learn it, if you know how I can do it with current literature, point me in the right direction. Instead I constantly hear the same thing `the magical compiler knows more than you, just don't even attempt anything`. Let me ,or in this case OP, decide whether he/she wants to let the compiler do it or learn how it does it.

Comment: @Samaursa: Nobody said that people shouldn't "understanding disassembly and how to optimize code." This is not a religious debate; it's a matter of simple fact. People have spent man-centuries hand-optimizing some routine only to find out that it means nothing to overall performance. Learning how to optimize algorithms is a highly-valuable skillset. Learning how to read assembly is a semi-valuable skillset. Learning how to write assembly routines is a skillset that is only rarely of use. And these days, the best optimizations come from better cache utilization, not hand assembly.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I agree with the time spent but for a curious/young mind, you will most likely not be able to convince just like that. Warn them, but also let them try. I bet everyone touched fire or put their finger in the electrical socket (ok, maybe not in North America since the sockets are all slits rather than round) even after their parents warned them not to. That's the only way to learn. What I hope is that out of all those who touch it and then stay away from it, a few will realize, this is what they love to do (and get better at it) and will never look back. Don't scare them away.

Comment: I won't engage in this discussion, but please @Samaursa don't use `code` formatting to empathize text...

Comment: What it comes down to though is "where is the most productive use of my time?"  I agree that learing assembly can be a useful skill (you understand better what the compiler does, etc) and it can be an interesting and/or fun thing.  But is actually using it for this kind of optimizing going to be more productive than learning different algorithms or than optimizing a different part of the program?  On a real project you're not going to have the time luxury so knowing when something is "good enough" and that it's time to stop is a more useful skill, IMO.

Comment: The majority? In mh01's answer & all over SO as you yourself stated. Your self-admitted profile is rookie/learner, so you've not spent 10+ years in the software development industry that many of us have. If you had, you wouldn't be so taken by the idea of "optimisation" as something cool and wicked and sweet; you'd be far more involved with the concept of "project delivery". The company I run engages in all kinds of projects; jobs that requires working smarter (algorithms), not longer (ASM) to get paid and avoid being litigated against on unfulfilled contractual obligations. THAT's the point.

Comment: @NickWiggill: I guess you haven't met many humble people (and ones who have not updated their SO profile in a while!) :) I admit I do not have 10+ years in software development like you, and therefore I do not (should not) reject anything you say; but, I do have experience in the gaming industry, and my answer and part of the rant was simply from experience. I am approaching the years where I have less and less time. If someone had guided my curiosity in my undergraduate years, I would be much better off. There is a huge emphasis on algorithms in undergrad, but not optimization nor assembly...

Comment: I personally know a few people whose job it is to do what I know I would love to do but cannot because I missed the boat. Now I am short on time and my responsibilities as a family member have increased 10-fold. Trying to get into this would be financial suicide for me. OP is still a student and if his program was anything similar to mine, there was a lot of emphasis on algorithms and data structures etc. After a while, you get tired of it and want to do something else for a little while. His mind (and mine) wandered to assembly optimization/programming. In my case people scared me of it...

Comment: Like I said before, warn him, yes, but also point him in the right direction. Anyway, I vote we close this lengthy discussion.

Answer (score 22):

The first tip you'll get is this - don't.

Modern compilers are actually really really good at optimizing code, and will be much more likely to do a better job of it than any self-rolled assembly language you may write.

The exception would be any specific case where you have determined for certain that the compiler is doing a bad job of optimizing, so that's the second tip.  There are no general guidelines here, you need to know your own code, know what it's doing, be able to jump into a disassembly of it, and be able to determine for absolute certain that the compiler is doing a bad job.

Even in this case you still may not want to.  You need to be certain that there is not going to be any ongoing maintenance overhead for you.  You may wish to come back to this code in 6 months time and modify part of it, or you may find an extremely subtle bug that's going to be more difficult to fix in an assembly language version.  Even if you think you've worked all the bugs out, once your program goes to the public bugs you never even thought could happen will become a reality for you.  That's quite an eye-opener (and a humbling experience).

And even if you're happy to accept that, you may still find that there is absolutely no measurable performance improvement as your main bottleneck could be somewhere completely different in your program.  So that brings me back to number 1 again.  Don't.

Answer (score 15):

Usually, solid optimisation doesn't depend on using Assembly, or doing micro-optimisations with code in higher level languages. If you read a lot of research papers (as I do -- or try to!), you'll see that oftentimes the improvements made to algorithms are at a broader conceptual, "qualitative" level, rather than at the more "quantitative" level of micro-optimisation. I would stress that order-of-magnitude gains are more likely to be found by looking at algorithms from this point of view, or from vectorising/parallelising existing solutions.

Having said that, I recently happened upon [this](http://jaymzroo.tripod.com/games.html), which may be a good route towards learning x86 ASM specifically for game developers.

---

**ADDENDUM**

Two sources off the top of my head:

- [The Algorithm Design Manual](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848000693) - Steve Skiena
- [Data Structures for Game Programmers](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1931841942) - Ron Penton and Andre LaMothe

Additionally, reading research papers is an excellent way to follow the thought processes of the wise as they optimise algorithms for better performance. Most often, gains are seen by:

- Reducing the use of the most costly operations (div, SQRT, trig ops, and conditionals, primarily);
- Improving cache performance through use of more efficient data structures, memory alignment, and reduced conditionals;
- Reducing quality of output in acceptable areas for improved performance;
- Vectorisation (SIMD);
- Parallelisation (threading, includes shifting tasks off to the GPU);
- And of course (increasingly rarely) hand-coded assembly. First inspecting C/C++ assemblies to see where the compiler is making non-optimal choices, of course. You will find more of this in older papers from the 80's and 90's, IME.

Reading research also keeps you at the cutting edge of your field, instead of waiting for that knowledge to filter down into the industry.

Comment: you talk about algorithm optimisation but you give no information on it, if we were to follow you advice and look at that instead could you give some direction ?

Comment: In fact, I do mention it; you need to _study_ algorithms, understanding what it is that computer scientists do to qualitatively improve performance. Immerse yourself in this enough, and in time, you begin to think in similar terms. Incremental efforts here pay off big time, as opposed to spending years (and I recently saw this mentioned on an ASM forum) mastering the ins and outs of (just) eg. x86 architecture. Hunt the big game: learn to whittle problems down to their very core, and then decide what is superfluous in order to optimise. See ref books above.

Comment: @NickWiggill What's your usual source of research papers?

Answer (score 3):

I think it might be too early.

Anyway, it is important to understand that the compiler itself does not produce slower code than the assembly equivalent, you don't get any performance simply from writing the same assembly code as the compiler would.

For a start at least concentrate on assembly-free optimizations. Igor Ostrovsky have a few good articles that demonstrate some of the basics: http://igoro.com/archive/fast-and-slow-if-statements-branch-prediction-in-modern-processors/

Do note that branch mispredictions and cache misses are what you should primarily optimize against, even if you have to pay by doing some extra arithmetic operations it is usually worth it to avoid an unpredictable branch or reading randomly from too much memory.

And of course, most importantly, optimize your algorithm first. A slow implementation of a fast algorithm will almost always be faster than a fast implementation of a slow algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

This book is exceptionally good for a text book.  But its not specifically geared towards optimization.
[Assembly Language for x86 Processors, 6th edition](http://kipirvine.com/asm/)

It's more about teaching the fundamentals of assembly, using MASM. Then towards the end of the book it gets into how to inline assembly with c++ and integrate it into bigger programs.

I put this up here because it makes sense to learn the fundamentals of assembly before you learn how to optimize programs with it.

I like this book because Irvine teaches you how to use the tools needed to write masm programs. He specifically goes into how to use the IDE (Visual Studio C++) and the debugger. Each chapter has a few videos dedicated towards solving problems.  Some of this information is available freely on the website listed.

Comment: "it makes sense to learn the fundamentals of assembly before you learn how to optimize programs with it" - good advice.